# Why is my SAX handler returning an object with no values? I am setting it just fine

Tags: java, xml, spring, sax

I'm writing a SAX parser for an xml, and the object it returns doesn't have the values that I am setting in the events.

My classes structure is like this:

```
public class ProductSAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

  private Product product;

  public ProductSAXHandler() {
     product = new Product();
  }

  public Product ParseXmlFile(String xml) {

     SAXParserFactory spf = new ...
     XMLReader parser = ....


     parser.parse(xml);


     return product;
  }


  public void StartElement(....) {


    for(int ...) { // looping through attributes

      if(qName == "description" && name == "sku") {
        product.setSKU(value);
      }
    }

   }

}
```

When I am in debug mode, the value of product does get set, and I can see that the product's  sku field has the correct value.

But for some reason the `product` object returned is just a new Product object with no values set during the parsing.

What am I doing wrong here?  It must be me not understanding how these events are fired etc.

**Update**

Very strange, in my if statement in set's the value of the attribute correctly to the SKU field of my product class, but when I am returning the product object in ParseXMLFile the SKU field is null.

**I guess the callbacks are firing at different times**, how am I suppose to return correctly then??

Comment: I don't see a return statement in `ParseXmlFile()`.

Comment: Is this the == vs. equals() thing again?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i forgot to write that in the question, but yes I have that.

Comment: @SkipHead no, like I said, when I am in debug mode, it goes to the line and sets the SKU properly.

Comment: Have you considered using JAXB to convert the XML to objects instead of doing it yourself.  Multiple implementations are available, and one is included in Java SE 6.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I have to stick with SAX for this.

Answer (score 5):

whatever you think you are doing, don't compare strings with "==", use `equals()`.